# Converting multivariate dataframe to univariate time series using R

Tags: r, time-series, data-mining, arima

These are the head of the data set I am using.

```
 Hour count
  <chr> <int>
1    00 22462
2    01 13293
3    02 10595
4    03  9371
5    04 14325
6    05 38598
```

To perform forecasting using auto arima I should convert this data into univariate.

```
make.univ(rsms,sms.hour,tname="TIME1", outname="MULTDV")
```

I used the above code to convert to univariate, but it gives an error.

> Error in data.frame(timedat = rep(0:(NREPOBS - 1), nrow(x)), outdat =
>   as.vector(t(dvs))) :    arguments imply differing number of rows:
>   4123938, 48

original dataset:

```
rsms [2million records(1 day data)] sample dataset : sms.hour[24
records (class(sms.hour) = "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"]
```

Can someone help me to solve this?

Comment: try using `auto.arima(rsms$count)`

Comment: thanks it helped me. but it does not generate best forecasting model.is there any way that i can enhance the arima model?

Answer (score 0):

Your data is already univariate. I'm not sure, but I think the lines below would make your data look like the output of a `make.univ()` call:

```
rsms$Hour <- as.numeric(rsms$Hour)
names(rsms) <- c("TIME", "MULTDV")
```

Comment: But when i execute auto.arima function                                                          > auto.arima(sms.hour)
{Error in auto.arima(sms.hour) : 
  auto.arima can only handle univariate time series}.........It generates an error.:-(